How can I compute this derivative
How can I compute the following derivative where $f$ is a differentiable function of two variables and $g$ and $h$ are also differentiable functions of one variable.
$$
\frac{d}{dx}f(g(x), h(x))
$$

https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Calculus/Calculus_(OpenStax)/14%3A_Differentiation_of_Functions_of_Several_Variables/14.05%3A_The_Chain_Rule_for_Multivariable_Functions
